# The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886

Tags: gpg

gpg errorW: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886

Comment: Hi Less Schmitt. Welcome to unix stackexchange! Your question is badly worded. But I can guess that you read some article online that contain shell code, and you copy pasted that on your machine. YOU SHOULD NEVER RUN CODE YOU DON'T UNDERSTAND WHAT YOU ARE DOING! However, for this particular matter, the original article, if properly written, should've aready provided you with the information regarding public key retrieval and signature verification. If you cannot find a proper tutorial to follow, you may need to read https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt before you take any next step.

Answer (score 2):

The message indicates your system is trying to access a Personal Package Archive (PPA) intended for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS "trusty", but `apt` does not have the GPG key to verify the integrity of packages in it.

A search on GPG key ID C2518248EEA14886 indicates the key seems to belong to [this Launchpad webpage.](https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/stable-daily)

Note that it is supposed to be a daily build of VLC for Ubuntu versions 16.04, 16.10 and 15.10... and it has not been updated in more than two years, so it looks like the PPA has transitioned on from 14.04 to newer versions of Ubuntu as time went on, and then been abandoned as those Ubuntu versions have become obsolete. 
For slightly newer Ubuntu releases, you should probably be using this PPA instead:
https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/master-daily

According to [this webpage](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/06/install-vlc-3-0-ubuntu), that PPA used to offer an up-to-date version of VLC for "Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and up", but this seems no longer to be the case: there are still some packages in the PPA for Ubuntu 16.04, but no VLC.

If you need a newer VLC for an old version of Ubuntu, this packager may be helpful:
https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf

His page contains a multitude of PPAs: either [his "vlc" PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/vlc) or [his "vlc-3" PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/vlc-3) might be appropriate for you. But even those will no longer provide any version of VLC for Ubuntu 14.04.

If you're using Ubuntu 14.04, you might have to remove the PPA configuration from your system to avoid the error messages, and keep the version of VLC you have currently installed, with the caveat that you won't be getting any updates for it, and future security updates to the base distribution might inadvertently cause that version of VLC to break.

[The end of standard support for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS was in April 2019](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), and the 14.04 release has moved on to the Extended Security Maintenance phase. The final End-of-Life for the 14.04 release will be in April 2022, but as the standard support has ended, you can no longer expect to get "latest and greatest" software for such an old version unless you compile it yourself. If you need an up-to-date version of VLC on the system, you should seriously consider upgrading to a newer LTS release.

Comment: Searching for that key Id on U&L has a few hits; possible duplicate candidates or answers?